# Tamper GET request parameter with Tamper Data in Firefox?

Tags: http, web-applications, httpwebrequest, fiddler, tampering

I am  able to tamper post request parameter with Tamper Data in firefox i.e when i make 
post request and i get the popup in firefox to change POST  request parameters but in case
of GET request, i  get the popup but there is no way to change the request parameter.

So question is Can't we change the request parameter thru Tamper Data/Fiddler?(Yes i agree
we can change it from browser address bar but that will be applicable once first request has been firect but i want to tamper some data in the very first Get Request. So i want to change GET request paramater with Tamer Data/Fiddler.Is it possible?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** do that using Tamper-Data. You could use a more advanced standalone-tool, like  **Web Scarab** ([Archived page by Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220204132553/https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) / [Source Code at SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/owasp/files/WebScarab/)) which will let you intercept and edit all portions of your web-requests.

Using fiddler, in conjunction with [`FiddlerScript`](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledge-base/fiddlerscript/modifyrequestorresponse) is also an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use Fiddler to tamper with any aspect of a request or response. You can do this using FiddlerScript or manually using breakpoints. To change traffic manually using breakpoints, watch this tutorial video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bo5kXMAcV0&list=PLvmaC-XMqeBbw72l2G7FG7CntDTErjbHc

Answer (score 0):

You can also use: `Live HTTP Headers` addon. Hope it help.

- [Archived addon page by Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20181122023338/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)
- [Archived project page by Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200628024648/http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/)

Edit 2023: Alternative addon
[HTTP Header Live](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-header-live/)